# Trying to use Passenger/Nginx for my Rails production server, 403 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to get my production server up and running on my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server, I followed this tutorial step by step,

http://excid3.com/blog/setting-up-ubuntu-12-04-with-ruby-1-9-3-nginx-passenger-and-postgresql-or-mysql/#.UUAVdhnZVQI

but when I load nginx, I just get a 403 error. Here is my `namei -om /home/deploy(user)/app`

```
 drwxr-xr-x root   root     /
 drwxr-xr-x deploy www-data home
 drwxr-xr-x deploy www-data deploy
 drwxr-xr-x deploy www-data knowyourroute
```

and then in my nginx.conf I have at the VERY top

`user deploy www-data;`

and then in the `server {` I have

```
listen 80;
server_name 10.0.0.30;
root /home/deploy/knowyourroute/public;
passenger_enabled on;

location / {
   root html;
   index index.html index.htm;
}

error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
root html;
}
```

I've googled the crap out of it tried changing permissions, groups, running it as root or running it as the user `deploy` but still nothing I'm running out of things to try if anybody has any idea that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-specify passenger_enabled in the location block.